# VBA Word copy full content with Restricted editing

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy, edit

My question is, in vba, how can I copy an opened full word document to the current word document, with copying EVERYTHING? No matter what I tried, I could not copy the Restrict Editing, only the rest of the content. I created the document. However, I would ALSO like to -copy- these restrictions, but I can't. I have the right to do it, but the restrictions are not created in the copy. I want to save the structure and code of the current file menu with the content from the old, pasted from another file.

I also tried this, it copies everything, but the restricted edit disappears.

```
    oWord.Activate
    oWord.Selection.WholeStory 'Select whole document
    oWord.Selection.Expand wdParagraph 'Expands your selection to current paragraph
    oWord.Selection.Copy 'Copy your selection
    ThisDocument.Activate
    Selection.EndKey wdStory 'Move to end of document
    Selection.Paste  'Pastes in the content
```

I tried that too, and it doesn't work. Last line give me Error 4218: This object surface is not supported.

```
    Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim oTarget As Document
    Dim oRng As Range
    Set oDoc = oWB
    Set oTarget = ThisDocument
    Set oRng = oTarget.Range
    oRng.FormattedText = oDoc.Range.FormattedText
```

Comment: This looks like the same question you posted a couple of days ago. Are you expecting a different answer today? Timothy Rylatt asked why you were trying to copy a complete document instead of using a SaveAs operation, which is still a valid question. But if, for some reason, you _must_ use a copy, have you tried unprotecting the file, copying, then reprotecting?

Comment: I posted it again because I couldn't change the original text and it said that I wanted to copy it "without everything", but I wanted to copy it "with everything".
The SaveAs solution is no good, because I want to keep the menu and code of the current, actual file, merged with the contents of the scanned file.
In other words: this would be an update, the current, extended code and menu functions would be added to an older word content. Or do you have other ideas for this?

Comment: “I couldn't change the original text” - that is what the edit link below the question is for.

Comment: Sorry, Kds, your explanation is not clarifying what you're trying to do. "I want to keep the menu and code of the current, actual file" A Save As can preserve all aspects of a file, including ribbon modifications and VBA. "merged with the contents of the scanned file" You didn't previously mention a scanned file, is that what you're trying to copy and paste? "this would be an update, the current, extended code and menu functions would be added to an older word content" If _extended code_ means VBA and _menu functions_ mean Ribbon mods, then no, copying and pasting won't solve your issues.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to overcomplicate things, but I'll try to be more detailed:
So I have a Word document, for my users, with some functions and support written in my own VBA. These include new menu items and menu groups that appear on the menu bar. If I update the VBA code, or create a new menu item, it is on the one hand available as a new version, but the content of the document (with Restricted Editing) contains only empty tables, columns, etc. On the other hand, I want anyone who wants to keep their own content to be able to update it with the new code and menu items.

Comment: This function would be served by the code that in the new version opens the user's old, own version, with its own content, which loads this content into the current, file (with Restricted Editing). So that is why any old content needs to be merged with the new VBA code and menu items.

Comment: From what you describe your code should be in a template (.dotm), not a document. The user would then create a document from your template and add content. As the document remains attached to its template the template can be updated without affecting the document.

Comment: Yes, that's right, the file is a template, docm.
Sounds interesting what you recommended, but how to do it?

Comment: A file with a docm extension is a document, *not* a template. For further information see https://shaunakelly.com/topic/word/templates.html